# C code for counting number of occurrences of a word in string

Tags: c, string, loops, while-loop

I am trying to write a function that accepts a string and a word, and output the number of times it appears inside the string.

My bid:

```
int CountWord(char *s, char *word) {
    char first = word[0];
    int i, j, count = 0;
    while (s[i] != '\0') {
        if (s[i] == first)
            for (j = 1; (s[i+j] == word[j]) && (word[j] != '\0') && (s[i+j] != '\0'); ++j) {
                if (word[j] == '\0')
                    ++count;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

The problem: It doesn't work on "code-blocks".

Thanks in advance for your appreciated help.

Comment: you haven't initialized `i` before using it. and you never increment it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- you do not initialize `i`
- you do not increment `i`
- the test `(word[j] != '\0')` in the `for` loop prevents the counting code from ever executing.
- a match cannot be found at the end of the string
- the count will be incorrect if `word` is the empty string.
- `int` might not have the required range for very long strings on some architectures.

Here is a corrected version:

```
size_t CountWord(const char *s, const char *word) {
    char first = word[0];
    size_t i, j, count = 0;

    if (first == '\0')
        return strlen(s) + 1;

    for (i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (s[i] == first) {
            for (j = 1; word[j] != '\0' && s[i + j] == word[j]; j++)
                continue;
            if (word[j] == '\0')
                count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Note that this implementation will return `2` for `CountWord("aaa", "aa")` which may or may not be the expected result. The specification must be precise and tell whether to count overlapping occurrences of `word` or just non overlapping matches.